# How to insert into table multiple geometry rows from function JSON param?

Tags: postgresql-9.6, postgis

My table:

```
CREATE TABLE Points
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('point_id_seq'::regclass),
    info character varying(20) NOT NULL,
    my_point geometry(Point,4326),
    CONSTRAINT points_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

JSON text:

```
{
  "points": [
    {"lat": 45.50884, "lng": -73.58781, "info": "x1"},
    {"lat": 41.56355, "lng": -81.57327, "info": "x2"},
    {"lat": 41.52335, "lng": -81.57423, "info": "x3"}
  ]
}
```

My function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_multiple_geom ( multiple_geom json )
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE success numeric default 0;

BEGIN
    -- this insert only 1 row...
    INSERT INTO POINTS(my_point, info)
      SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(lng,lat),4326), info;                                                              

  RETURN success;
END;

$BODY$;
```

Comment: I guess your question is really "how do I extract the long/lat pairs & info from JSON and iterate over them to insert?"

Comment: Hi  Philᵀᴹ, yes, this was the final goal. Thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest the array values using [json_array_elements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html) function and `->>` operator:

```
create table t (data json);

insert into t 
values ('{"points": [
    {"lat": 45.50884, "lng": -73.58781, "info": "x1"},
    {"lat": 41.56355, "lng": -81.57327, "info": "x2"},
    {"lat": 41.52335, "lng": -81.57423, "info": "x3"}]}'::json);

select points->>'lat' as lat,
       points->>'lng' as lng,
       points->>'info' as info
from
     (select json_array_elements(data->'points') as points
      from t) p;
```

```
lat      | lng       | info
:------- | :-------- | :---
45.50884 | -73.58781 | x1;
41.56355 | -81.57327 | x2;
41.52335 | -81.57423 | x3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=12832963e2daf02ee562b11956b993d7)*

Now change your function by:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_multiple_geom (multiple_geom json)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

DECLARE success numeric default 0;

BEGIN
    -- this insert only 1 row...
    INSERT INTO POINTS(my_point, info)
      SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point((points->>'lat')::text::float8, 
                                 (points->>'lng')::text::float8), 
                                  4326), 
                        (points->>'info')::character varying
      FROM (SELECT json_array_elements(multiple_geom ->'points') AS points) p;

    RETURN success;
END;

$BODY$;
```

And try to use it:

```
DO $$
DECLARE data JSON;
BEGIN
    data := '{"points": [
    {"lat": 45.50884, "lng": -73.58781, "info": "x1"},
    {"lat": 41.56355, "lng": -81.57327, "info": "x2"},
    {"lat": 41.52335, "lng": -81.57423, "info": "x3"}]}'::json;

    PERFORM add_multiple_geom(data);
END $$;
```

```
SELECT * FROM Points;
```

```
id | info | my_point                                          
-: | :--- | :-------------------------------------------------
 1 | x1   | 0101000020E6100000C5724BAB21C14640C190D5AD9E6552C0
 2 | x2   | 0101000020E610000095D4096822C84440C971A774B06454C0
 3 | x3   | 0101000020E6100000492EFF21FDC2444074982F2FC06454C0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=12832963e2daf02ee562b11956b993d7)*

Comment: Hi McNets, your solution was wonderful. Thanks for help :-)

Comment: I'm glad to help.